# How to get the data from specific table after cutting top 5% and bottom 5%.Please suggest me right way

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a query in pl/sql to get the data from specific table after cutting top 5% and bottom 5% from table.Please suggest me right way.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT fu.user_name,
    TRUNC((fcr.actual_completion_date - fcr.actual_start_date) * 86400) run_time
    CASE
      WHEN fcpt.program_name = 'ABC'
      THEN
        (SELECT s.user_request_set_name
        FROM fnd_request_sets_tl s
        WHERE s.application_id = fcr.argument1)
      WHEN fcpt.program_name = 'XYZ'
      THEN
       (SELECT s.user_stage_name
        FROM fnd_request_set_stages_tl s
        WHERE s.set_application_id = fcr.argument1)
      ELSE SUBSTR (fcpt.program_name, 1, 1000)
    END
  FROM fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcpt,
    REQUESTS_HIST fcr,
    fnd_user fu,
    fnd_responsibility_vl frv
  WHERE requested_start_date BETWEEN to_date('2017-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date('2017-02-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
   ORDER BY run_time)
    WHERE rownum <=(SELECT COUNT(1)-(COUNT(1)*5)/100 FROM fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcpt,
    REQUESTS_HIST fcr
  WHERE requested_start_date BETWEEN to_date('2017-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date('2017-02-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
    ) ;
```

Error:
Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 23
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Comment: Which Oracle DBMS version are you using?

Comment: I would also make sure that I properly understand the sentence "after less 5 % from top and 5% percent from bottom". Do you expect to get 90% of records from the middle of the table (cutting top 5% and bottom 5%)?

Comment: There's no PL/SQL in your example. Why do you want a procedural solution? I don't know what your tables look like or what "after less 5% from top and 5% percent from bottom" means exactly, but you might look at the [ntile](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions127.htm) function.

Comment: You might check Tom Kyte's page.  Look for "getting rows N through M of a result set".  Does not use analytics though.

Comment: Hi kpater87, I'm using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production.Yes you are right I am expecting to get 90% of records from the middle of the table (cutting top 5% and bottom 5%).

Comment: Hi Mukit, can you add what problem or error you got when you tried with your SQL Query.

Comment: Look into the CUME_DIST analytic function.  You will get the distribution and can filter out 0-5 and 95-100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your below part returns value as 95:

```
rownum <=(SELECT COUNT(1)-(COUNT(1)*5)/100 FROM fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcpt
```

However it will return only rows with last 5 percent rows trimmed

I have added minus to subtract top 5 percent values ,so final solution is:

```
with 
temp as 
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT fu.user_name,
TRUNC((fcr.actual_completion_date - fcr.actual_start_date) * 86400) run_time
CASE
  WHEN fcpt.program_name = 'ABC'
  THEN
    (SELECT s.user_request_set_name
    FROM fnd_request_sets_tl s
    WHERE s.application_id = fcr.argument1)
  WHEN fcpt.program_name = 'XYZ'
  THEN
   (SELECT s.user_stage_name
    FROM fnd_request_set_stages_tl s
    WHERE s.set_application_id = fcr.argument1)
  ELSE SUBSTR (fcpt.program_name, 1, 1000)
END
FROM fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcpt,
REQUESTS_HIST fcr,
fnd_user fu,
fnd_responsibility_vl frv
WHERE requested_start_date BETWEEN to_date('2017-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date('2017-02-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
ORDER BY run_time)  
WHERE rownum <=(SELECT COUNT(1)-(COUNT(1)*5)/100 FROM fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcpt,
REQUESTS_HIST fcr
WHERE requested_start_date BETWEEN to_date('2017-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date('2017-02-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
)
)
select * from temp
minus
(select * from temp where rownum<=(
SELECT (COUNT(1)*5)/100 FROM fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcpt,
REQUESTS_HIST fcr
WHERE requested_start_date BETWEEN to_date('2017-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date('2017-02-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
)
);
```